# API request with R

Tags: r, api, geocoding

I try to do geocoding of French addresses. I'd like to use the following website : http://adresse.data.gouv.fr/

There is an example on this website on how is working the API but I think it's some Linux code and I'd like to translate in R code. The aim is to give a csv file with addresses and the result should be geo coordinates.

Linux code (example give on the website)

```
http --timeout 600 -f POST http://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/search/csv/ data@path/to/file.csv
```

I tried to "translate" this in R with the following code

```
library(httr)
library(RCurl)
queryResults=POST("http://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/search/csv/",body=list(data=fileUpload("file.csv"))) 
result_geocodage=content(queryResults)
```

But unfortunately I have a bad request error.

Does somebody knows what I'm missing in the translation to R?

Thanks!

Comment: Ok thank you, I edit my question!

Comment: I see now. The site's API uses Python's [httpie](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/httpie) package, a command line http client. You will need to obtain post data. Try RCurl's [postForm()](http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/installed/RCurl/html/postForm.html). URI=`http://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/search/csv/` and parameter, `data="path/to/file.csv"'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example. First, some example data plus the request:

```
library(httr)
df <- data.frame(c("13 Boulevard Chanzy", "Gloucester St"), 
                 c("93100 Montreuil", "Jersey"))
write.csv2(df, tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".csv"))
res <- POST("http://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/search/csv/", 
            timeout(600), 
            body = list(data = upload_file(tf)))
```

Then, the result:

```
content(res, sep = ";", row.names = 1)
# c..13.Boulevard.Chanzy....Gloucester.St.. c..93100.Montreuil....Jersey.. latitude longitude
# 1                       13 Boulevard Chanzy                93100 Montreuil 48.85825  2.434462
# 2                             Gloucester St                         Jersey 49.46712  1.145554
# result_label result_score result_type                result_id result_housenumber
# 1                13 Boulevard Chanzy 93100 Montreuil         0.88 housenumber ADRNIVX_0000000268334929                 13
# 2 2 Résidence le Jersey 76160 Saint-Martin-du-Vivier         0.24 housenumber ADRNIVX_0000000311480901                  2
# result_name result_street result_postcode            result_city                       result_context result_citycode
# 1    Boulevard Chanzy            NA           93100              Montreuil 93, Seine-Saint-Denis, Île-de-France           93048
# 2 Résidence le Jersey            NA           76160 Saint-Martin-du-Vivier  76, Seine-Maritime, Haute-Normandie           76617
```

Or, just the coordinates:

```
subset(content(res, sep = ";", row.names = 1, check.names = FALSE), select = c("latitude", "longitude"))
# latitude longitude
# 1 48.85825  2.434462
# 2 49.46712  1.145554
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's perfect!

Comment: An update on the parsing. In `httr v1.4`, the line `content(res, sep = ";", row.names = 1)` gives an error because the function `readr::read_csv` used to read the content does not take `sep` as an argument. My quick workaround is to parse to text with `txt = httr::content(res, as="text")` and then read the txt with `readr::read_delim(txt, delim=";")`.

Comment: In the help of the function `httr::content` it is warned that when "... using content() in a package, DO NOT use on as = "parsed". Instead, check the mime-type is what you expect, and then parse yourself. This is safer, as you will fail informatively if the API changes, and you will protect yourself against changes to httr."